# NSString object not initialized properly

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

Can somebody tell me what I am doing wrong here. I am trying to initialize a string from a list of predefined names, but for some reason it doesn't work for NSString that is a class field:

```
MyController.h:

@interface MyController:UIViewController
{
    NSString *text;
}


MyController.m:

-(void) viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSArray *list = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"A", @"B", @"C", nil];

    NSString* temp= [list objectAtIndex:0]; // temp = "A"

    text = [list objectAtIndex:0];  // Why text = nil ????
    text = @"Hello";   // does not work either
}
```

Comment: That should definitely work. Have you stepped through with the debugger?

Comment: That's what the debugger said.

Comment: In my experience, sometimes the debugger can be wrong, have you tried logging that `text` is at those points?

Comment: You are right.. the debugger needs to be debugged

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the debugger is wrong in this case.

Comment: .. unless he's building with ARC enabled. Then it's fine.

Comment: @BenClayton Agreed.  Should we have to guess though?

Answer (score -1):

Try setting text equal to `NSString *text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [list objectAtIndex:0]];`

Comment: Why use `stringWithFormat` when it's simply a reference count issue?